# Create a function to record order value for adds tracking

Tags: woocommerce, google-ads-api, bing

I need to create a function on which will record the 'Total Order value' on my order confirmation page in woocommerce, the function will be be used by microsoft ads to record the value of order against what i have spent, anybody any experience of doing this?

The code provided by microsoft is:

window.uetq.push('event', '', {'revenue_value': Replace_with_Variable_Revenue_Function(), 'currency': 'Replace_with_Currency_Code'});

So i need to create a function called 'revenue_value' for example which will pass the total order value to the above code.
Anybody point me the right direction.

Comment: In your thankyou page (default where your client returns ) you have to include your tag and pass the data you want to collect init thats all. You can use plugin for that too such as  Pixel Manager Pro for WooCommerce.

Comment: Thanks, i can insert the code fine and it tracks how many orders i receive but not the order value as the code from microsoft require a function to extract the value, ive tried plugins as well but they still dont record the revenue?